# Trigger PHP Code in the same page

Tags: php, .net, triggers

I have one php file named `sample.php`, which includes the following code:

```
$abc = new DOTNET("FirstDotNet, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "FirstDotNet.Class1");

echo $abc->Connect();
echo $abc->PrintItem();

echo "<img src=\"image.png\" onclick=\"\" />";
```

What I want is:

1. Run first two row codes in the beginning of page load (this is ok as usual)
2. Don't allow the third line code in the beginning of the page load.
3. Allow to the third line of code to run when I click the image.

Those actions must be on the same `php` page, not with form posting or with the help of another php file.

Is this possible? How I can trigger the third row of code after the page is loaded?

Comment: PHP is a server side language, it doesn't know when the page is loaded in the browser and when elements are clicked.  You need to utilize Javascript, or client side scripting.

Comment: Welp, requirements are impossible to meet. Aborting...

Comment: You realize the third line simply executes `$abc->PrintItem()` before returning the html response, right? That all of this code runs BEFORE the page is loaded in the browser, yielding text that is interpreted as markup? What do you expect that function to do?

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't do this, not in one page. I would look into Javascript to control the visibility of the IMG object.

PHP runs the whole file and returns the results to the browser. It doesn't allow you to stop and interact from the browser.